# Generating binary numbers of n digits in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'd like to generate binary numbers of `n` digits from 0 to 2^n-1. For example of 3 digits, "000", "001", "010", ..., "111" (0 to 7 in decimal). The way I used is to use `java.lang.Integer.toBinaryString()` method and add zeros if necessary like the following:

```
(defn pad-zero [s n]
  (str (reduce str (repeat (- n (count s)) "0")) s))

(defn binary-permutation [n]
  (map (fn [s] (pad-zero s n))
       (map #(Integer/toBinaryString %) (range 0 (Math/pow 2 n)))))
```

With this code, I can generate what I want like this. For 3 digits:

```
(binary-permutation 3)
=> ("000" "001" "010" "011" "100" "101" "110" "111")
```

But this codes look a little verbose.
Aren't there any ways better or more clojure way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simplify the formatting using [cl-format](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.pprint-api.html#clojure.pprint/cl-format) from [clojure.pprint](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.pprint-api.html):

```
(defn binary-permutation [n]
  (map (partial cl-format nil "~v,'0B" n) (range 0 (Math/pow 2 n))))
```

You may also be interested to know that `(Math/pow 2 n)` is equivalent to `(bit-shift-left 1 n)`.

Another way to express this would be in term of [selections](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/blob/math.combinatorics-0.0.3/src/main/clojure/clojure/math/combinatorics.clj#L107) from [clojure.math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/):

```
(defn binary-permutation [n]
  (map (partial apply str) (selections [0 1] n)))
```

Comment: @noahz cl-format is an output formatting function from Common Lisp that is available in Clojure (akin to printf in other languages). It just makes it a bit easier to output padded binary numbers as the OP was doing. Saving a keystrokes. If you have an alternative feel free to post it as well.

Comment: @noahz And if you're asking why use one version of this function over the other. I'm not sure. I'd say the range based version is a bit simpler to grok. It's just counting. But combinatorics solution is interesting as well.

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin The first one using cl-format is exactly what I tried to do. However, what I really wanted to get was not binary string like "011" but was [0 1 1], and using selections would best fit what I wanted. Not necessarily map the result of selections. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn binary-permutation [n]
  (for [x (range (Math/pow 2 n))]
    (apply str (reverse (take n (map #(bit-and 1 %) (iterate #(bit-shift-right % 1) x)))))))

(defn pad-zero [s n]
  (apply str (take-last n (concat (repeat n \0) s))))
```